# How to access Servlet Session in CXF Interceptor?

Tags: java, jax-ws, cxf

I have an "in" CXF Interceptor, I want to access the the Servlet Session in its `handleMessage()` method. My Interceptor extends `AbstractPhaseInterceptor`.

I want to access the session to store some info about the user as my web service client maintains sessions.

I can already access the session in my web services.

Comment: hey, I am having similar issue. please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30862397/how-to-invalidate-session-by-cxf-interceptor

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to do

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)message.get("HTTP.REQUEST");
```

to get the HttpServletReqest where you can then grab the session from it.

Comment: One can also use the constant ``AbstractHTTPDestination.HTTP_REQUEST`` as a replacement for the hardcoded string.

Comment: @phineas can u help with my issue.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30862397/how-to-invalidate-session-by-cxf-interceptor